# JSOUP error FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, syntax-error, jsoup

Im trying to figure out JSOUP, so i found a very simple example, and no matter what i do i get this error:

I have importet:
"jsoup-1.7.2.jar" to /libs

Set internetpermission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

The Main Activity:

```
package iha.itsmap.jsoup2;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.print(title);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error is this:

```
05-28 11:20:12.873: W/dalvikvm(7142): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{iha.itsmap.jsoup2/iha.itsmap.jsoup2.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at iha.itsmap.jsoup2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-28 11:20:12.903: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     ... 11 more
```

Can anyone tell why this error is occurring?

If i comment out this code:

```
//  try {
//      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
//      String title = doc.title();
//      System.out.print(title);
//  } catch (IOException e) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//      e.printStackTrace();
//  }
```

The app wont crash, but i still seem to get this error, i dont know if its important

```
05-28 11:13:37.484: E/Trace(6996): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using Android 3.0+.  Network access on the UI thread on Honeycomb or above will cause `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) to perform asynchronous work on your user interface.

Comment: I moved it into a buttonclick and AsyncTask and this worked!
Thank you!
This it my first post, so should i update the working code in my first post?

Comment: Glad to learn that it worked.  Feel free to edit your post above to add the code that worked!